# Compressed (zip) Cannot create output file - error

Tags: vbscript, zip

I am using VBscript to scan folders, create zip files and add files to them (compress), but as I run my script on folders with a lot of files, I get the following error: "Compressed (zip) Cannot create output file"

my zip handling code is as follows:

```
Dim objFSO
Set objFSO= CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject"

Function PreformZip(objFile,target,zip_name, number_of_file)

  Set shell = CreateObject("WScript.Shell")  
  zip_target = target + "\" + zip_name +".zip" 
  If Not objFSO.FileExists(zip_target) Then
    MakePathIfNotExist(target) 
    NewZip(zip_target)
  Else
    If number_of_file=0 Then
        objFSO.DeleteFile(zip_target)
        NewZip(zip_target)
    End if
  End If

  Set zipApp = CreateObject("Shell.Application")
  aSourceName = Split(objFile, "\")
  sSourceName = (aSourceName(Ubound(aSourceName)))
  zip_file_count = zipApp.NameSpace(zip_target).items.Count
  zipApp.NameSpace(zip_target).Copyhere objFile, 16
  On Error Resume Next
  sLoop = 0
  Do Until zip_file_count < zipApp.NameSpace(zip_target).Items.Count
    Wscript.Sleep(100)
    sLoop = sLoop + 1
  Loop
  On Error GoTo 0
End Function

Sub NewZip(zip)
  Set new_zip = objFSO.CreateTextFile(zip)
  new_zip.Write Chr(80) & Chr(75) & Chr(5) & Chr(6) & String(18, 0)  
  new_zip.Close
  Set new_zip = Nothing 
  WScript.Sleep(5000)
End Sub

Function MakePathIfNotExist(DirPath)
Dim FSO, aDirectories, sCreateDirectory, iDirectory

Set FSO = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
If FSO.FolderExists(DirPath) Then
  Exit Function
End If

aDirectories = Split(DirPath, "\")
sCreateDirectory = aDirectories(0)
For iDirectory = 1 To UBound(aDirectories)
  sCreateDirectory = sCreateDirectory & "\" & aDirectories(iDirectory)
  If Not FSO.FolderExists(sCreateDirectory) Then
  FSO.CreateFolder(sCreateDirectory)
  End If
Next
End Function

Function Recursion(DirectoryPath)
Dim FSO : Set FSO = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")

If FSO.FolderExists(DirectoryPath) Then Exit Function
Call Recursion(FSO.GetParentFolderName(DirectoryPath))
FSO.CreateFolder(DirectoryPath)
End Function
```

I first thought I'm not waiting long enough after creating the zip, but I even tried it with 10 seconds wait after each zip and I still get the same error.

How can I solve it?

If there is no solution, is there an alternative way to make a zip? The script is not only for my own use so I don't want ro relay on a software which needs to be installed?

Comment: Please make the code sample [self-contained](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve), so that we can reproduce the problem. The code worked for me when I removed the call to the undefined function `MakePathIfNotExist()` and added the missing definition of `objFSO` and an actual call to `PreformZip()`.

Comment: I've added the missing functions and definitions.
Like I said, the code works, but only if the folders and subfolders have a few files, if I need to make a lot of zip files then I get the error.

Comment: I think that `zipApp.NameSpace(zip_target).Copyhere` wont wait for the copy process to be complete.`Sleep` might need to be longer. There could be other ways around it. What is "a lot of files" might take more than 10 seconds

Comment: It won't wait, but waiting more then 10 sec per file is not a reliable solution and it takes too much time.

Comment: Agreed. The you should consider using another zipping solution like 7zip instead

Comment: Its not that much of an option, I can't install it on every end user's computer. I even tried 30 second wait just for the sets and even that failed after about 20 zips (with 1 file each).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, after a great amount of research I found out that there is no possible way to fix this problem when using shell to perform zip.

I solved this issue by using **za7.exe (7-zip)** in the following way:

```
Dim zipParams 
zipParams = "a -tzip"
Dim objShell: Set objShell = CreateObject("WScript.Shell")  
command = zip_exe_location + " " + zipParams + " " + zip_target + " " + SourceFile
objShell.Run Command, 0 ,true
```

the **"a"** in the zip parameters means "add to file" and **-tzip** sets the type of the file as zip.

Answer (score 0):

Although `Folder.CopyHere` method does not return a value and no notification is given to the calling program to indicate that the copy has completed, you could wait with next code snippet and I hope you can see proper (re)placement in your script:

```
On Error GoTo 0
zipApp.NameSpace(zip_target).Copyhere objFile _
      , 4 +8 +16 +256 +512 +1024
Wscript.Sleep( 100)
On Error GoTo 0
```

Notice: no waiting `Do..Loop`, this `Wscript.Sleep( 100)` is sufficient to zip small files or start progress dialog box in case of huge files - and your script will wait for it...

Notice: no `'On Error Resume Next`. Avoid invoking `On Error Resume Next` if you do not handle errors...

Flags used as follows.

```
Const FOF_SILENT            = &h0004 'ineffective?
Const FOF_RENAMEONCOLLISION = &h0008 'ineffective?
Const FOF_NOCONFIRMATION    = &h0010 '
Const FOF_SIMPLEPROGRESS    = &h0100 'ineffective?
Const FOF_NOCONFIRMMKDIR    = &h0200 '
Const FOF_NOERRORUI         = &h0400 '
```

Unfortunately, in some cases, such as compressed (`.zip`) files, some option flags may be ignored by design [(sic!) by MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb787866(v=vs.85).aspx)!

If `FOF_SILENT` flag ineffective, then user could *Cancel* zipping process...

If `FOF_RENAMEONCOLLISION` flag ineffective, then newer file of the same name is not zipped, existing zip file keeps previous version without caution against; only existing folder brings on an extra error message...

Those could be fixed up as well, but it's subject of another question...

Comment: First of all thanks for the replay,
I did not understand why do you say that your script will wait in case I zip a big file, as I see it, I will start the zipping process and after 100 milliseconds will continue with the code even if the transfer did not complete.
Secondly, how does it solve the problem that the file is not copied to the zip? it seems like the other flag are irrelevant to the problem, and its not likely that the loop caused it.

Comment: This works for me in arbitrary combination: zip a file, e.g. `aa = PreformZip( "C:\Temp\debug.txt","C:\Temp","mof", 1)` or zip a folder, e.g. `aa = PreformZip( "C:\rsit\","C:\Temp","mof", 1)`; now I got around  the `FOF_RENAMEONCOLLISION` flag ineffectivity... But make your mind easy, follow Matt's advice - there is the command line version in 7-zip...